# Salesforce REST api firewall issue

Tags: rest, salesforce, firewall

I am connecting to Salesforce REST Api to retrive Account and Contact objects.

I am able to login and get back the instance url after authentication. The next call to retrive objects using SOCL is coming back with error, "The remote name could not be resolved".

We are using Bluecoat firewall. Anyone has faced the issue before? Any idea what needs doing?

The main confusion here is, login.salesforce.com is the first call and it works, whereas eu11.salesforce.com is the second call and that fails. Thanks in advance for your help